# EmberJS: ArrayController with Dynamic Segments (Router) but not Store

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i was wondering how I could build a "simple" app for:

```
/photos/ (shows all photos – via ArrayController but without a remote service)
/photos/1  ... /photos/2  (shows one photo)
```

Can anyone offer a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a route that matches the url you want:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    // this will give you ~/#/photos
    this.route('photos') 
    // this will give you ~/#/photos/1 (or whatever number)   
    this.route('photo', { path: '/photos/:photo_id' }); 
});
```

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/AabL8/

If you want to do nested views, like displaying a list of thumbs and when clicking the thumb you see the picture in its actual size underneath the list, then you'll have to do it slightly different by using route resources, nested like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {    
    this.resrouce('photos', function() {
        this.route('photo', { path: '/:photo_id' });    
    });
});
```

If you do it this way, you'll have to add an `{{outlet}}` in the "photos" template
and add `Photos` in the name of the classes that is responsible for a single photo object

- `PhotoRoute` becomes `PhotosPhotoRoute`
- `data-template-name="photo"` becomes `data-template-name="photos/photo"`

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/JfRbf/

Comment: 12 Points. Thank you Milky!

Comment: One more thing: If i want to populate the ArrayController during "runtime" how would that look like? Do I really need the "store"?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. You don't need `store` unless you're using Ember-Data (models and all of that). When you say populate the controller un runtime, what do you mean by that? what's your use case?

Comment: Usecase: As a user I can drag and drop images to my browser, so that I can create a slideshow an the fly.

Comment: Ok, so you'll simply create a new `Photo` record and store it; your controller should have its `content` automatically updated with the new record once you commit it with the store.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing to get all the info from the image when you drag it to the page, but once you have, all you need to do is add a record to your store. I've modified one of these fiddle examples to show you how to save a record: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/T24b4/

Comment: BTW: In your first example "App.PhotoRoute = Em.Route.extend()" is never called. But the demo works anyhow ;-)